# How do i write a SOQL to extract opportunities that are in between two date time fields

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to write a SOQL to extract all opportunities that started and ended between a certain date and time.  I have two custom date time fields OppStartDateTime and OppEndDateTime.

Comment: @nhmbobby,, welcome to SFSE, please take some time to read through [ask] and take the [tour]. Afterwards, please **[edit]** your psot to include what you have tried, as metnioned by David. This forum is not a free code writng service, we are more than glad to help you sort out any problems you are f acing in code you have written, asking "how to" questions without any research effort, or attempt to do so is usually not well received, which explains the downvote. Please udpate your psot accordingly, thanks!

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have worded my questions differently.  I have tried the following SOQL  before I asked the question:

Comment: Sorry I guess I should have worded my questions differently.  I have tried the following SOQL  before I asked the question:                                                                         SELECT Id, Name, Title__c, 
                  FROM Opportunity
                  WHERE  OppStartDateTime__c <=: '2018-07-01T11:30:00Z' AND            OppEndDateTime__c >=:2018-07-15T11:30:00Z'

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
Date startDate = date.newinstance(2011, 1, 1);
Date endDate = date.newinstance(2011, 12, 31);

List<Opportunity> oppLst = [
    SELECT o.CreatedDate, o.Id, o.LastModifiedDate  
    FROM Opportunity o 
    WHERE o.OppStartDateTime > :startDate 
    AND o.OppEndDateTime < :endDate 
    ORDER BY o.LastModifiedDate
];
```

Comment: other than TRY this, mind providing an explanation?